# Linq on a Datasource of list type

Tags: linq, list, generics, dynamic

I have several entity objects for eg. Customer, Orders which derive from IComparable
and all all mapped to database fields.

I bind the grid at runtime as a `List<Customer>`, `List<Orders>` etc.

I am writing a custom column class
where I can get `Parent.DataSource` (it would always be `List<>`) but the actual type is unknown. I need to convert that to a list type (maybe `IList`) so I could write linq queries against the datasource.

something like

```
IList t = Parent.DataSource as IList
var qry = from cl in t
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you've suggested as the answer?

Comment: I cannot do a linq select on IList

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to convert your  `Parent.DataSource` into the appropriate type via LINQ's `Cast()` method, and query against it:

```
var query = from customer in Parent.DataSource.Cast<Customer>()
            where customer.Foo == "Bar"
            select customer;
```

Comment: I don't know what type is the source... Can I do something more generic??? The datasource could be one of 100 object entities I have.

Comment: If you have no idea what type it could be, how could you expect it to be converted?

Comment: @Graci: It's difficult to query against something without knowing the type.  You can use OfType<Customer>() to retrieve customers, and check to see if it's empty - but that's going to be ugly.  I'd consider seeing if there's a way to make a custom interface that would work in your scenario, and have all of your entities implement it...

Comment: Can I pass create a method that takes a generic list as parameter and write linq off that?

Comment: @Graci: Yes, or you could make it a generic method - ie:  `public IList<T> Create<T>(...)`, then call it as `Create<Customer>()`

Comment: Also, how would custom interface help?

Comment: @Graci: You could have DataSource be defined as `IList<ICustomInterface>` - only helps if you are using members of hte interface, not concrete classes.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Cast` in Linq .

```
var query = from customers in Parent.DataSource.Cast<Customer>()
            select customers;
```

`Cast<Customer>` will convert your Parent.DataSource to your corresponding Customer entity